# Javascript each function works only for the last element

Tags: javascript, each

I have to calculate, for a school support association, fees based on the number of books shipped (number limited to 20), and based on 4 different dimensions.

So I have an array supposed giving me the corresponding value, the problem is the "each" loop based on a field with a particular class only works only for the last element instead of all class elements.

|-col1-|--col2--|-col3-|--col4--|-col5-|--col6--|-col6--|...

---

|-dim1-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees--|...

|-dim2-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees--|...

|-dim3-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees--|...

|-dim4-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees-|-number-|-fees--|...

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hafid/L91gru0f/)

```
function calculate(){
$(".dim").each(function(){
    var idn = $(this).attr("id");
    var id = idn.replace("dim", "");
    var dm = $(this).val();
    var nb = $("#num"+id).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i][0] == dm && myArray[i][1] > nb) {
            $("#result").val(myArray[i][2]);
        }
        if (myArray[i][0] == dm && myArray[i][3] > nb) {
            $("#result").val(myArray[i][4]);
        }
        if (myArray[i][0] == dm && myArray[i][5] > nb) {
            $("#result").val(myArray[i][6]);
        }
        if (myArray[i][0] == dm && myArray[i][7] > nb) {
            $("#result").val(myArray[i][8]);
        }
        if (myArray[i][0] == dm && myArray[i][9] > nb) {
            $("#result").val(myArray[i][10]);
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry but the problem has nothing to do with "each" function, it was the coronavirus epidemic that made me lose my mind, the solution to the problem is precisely to remove "each" function, thanks to Abhishek and Bryan

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned what does myArray contains, I think you should use "else if" rather than all "if" statement.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, the code only works for the last fledset, I think "else vs elseif" doesn't matter in this problem

Answer (score 0):

If I read your description correctly I believe this should suit your needs.

```
function calculate(){
  var total = 0
  $(".dim").each(function(){
     var idn = $(this).attr("id");
     var id = idn.replace("dim", "");
     var dm = parseInt($(this).val());
     var nb = parseInt($("#num"+id).val()) -1;
     total += myArray[dm][nb]
  });
  $("#result").val(total);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan but select and input number give wrong values, I want just thas the loop work for all fieldset instead of the last one